# Azure function read appsetting.json

Tags: c#, azure, function, azure-functions, azureservicebus

Azure function wont read configuration in appsetting.json, it rather reads from local.settings.json

Startup

```
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {


    }

    public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        var context = builder.GetContext();

        builder.ConfigurationBuilder
                .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, "appsettings.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
                .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, $"appsettings.{context.EnvironmentName}.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    }


}
```

Trigger

```
        [FunctionName("func")]
    public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("topicName", "subName", Connection = "ConnectionString")] EmployeeMessageModel employeeMessage)
    {


    }
```

Error: Service Bus account connection string 'ConnectionString' does not exist. Make sure that it is a defined App Setting.

Appsettings.json

```
{"ConnectionString": "ConnectionString"}
```

If I add it to local.settings.json it will find it. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: When working locally, it has to have the connection string in local.settings.json

Comment: In application settings only environment variables(keys) is supported not the connection string, connection string is only supported in local settings.json

Answer (score 2):

In portal, if you want to add connection string, you need to add in Application settings of Configuration tab as below:

[image]

[image]

Something like this you need to do when you publish to portal.

If you want to connect a service bus in local you need add service bus connection string in Local.settings.json as below:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
      "Connection": "Connection string here"
  }
}
```

[image]

In application settings only environment variables(keys) is supported not the connection string, connection string is only supported in local settings.json
So you need to use Local settings for that.