# Isolated azure function with service bus trigger - connection string from azure app configuration

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0, azure-app-configuration

I have some problems in running the azure function (isolated one) based on .net 6. I would like to get the connection string to the service bus from azure app config.
All other settings are succesfuly fetched and served with IOptions pattern: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0
With connection string to service bus, I am getting following error when I am trying to run the function locally:

```
 Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus: Service Bus account connection string 'AzureServiceBus' does not exist. Make sure that it is a defined App Setting.
```

The functioln looks like this:

```
using Api.Contracts.BusMessage;

namespace Api.Functions.Queues;

public class Test
{
    private const string FunctionName = "func";

    private readonly ILogger<Test> _logger;

    public Test(ILogger<Test> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [Function(FunctionName)]
    public async Task Run(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("func", Connection = "AzureServiceBus")]
        BusMessage<string> message)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Processing queue trigger message {@Message}", message);
    }
}
```

Is it even possible to get connection string from Azure App Configuration?

Comment: Have you tried looking here?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#connection-string

Comment: I think if you put in your localsettings.json it will pick it up when run locally.  It will pick it up from the Azure App Config when run in Azure.

Comment: Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73822115/azure-function-read-appsetting-json/73822752#73822752) thread.Does this help?

Comment: Using this article https://dev.to/kenakamu/net-6-service-bus-trigger-azure-function-part-1-50h4] I have managed to use Managed Identity inside Azure, but the connection string, any way, must be placed in "Configuration" tab of function resource. When I am trying to put it as "ServiceBusConnection:fullyQualifiedNamespace" in Azure App Configuration I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Service bus connection [must come from Function App's own App Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=isolated-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#connections). It is possible to reference values from Azure App Configuration in the Function App's App settings. See [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-configuration-references). If you are pulling settings from Azure App Configuration in at runtime of your function, then that will not be usable for the Service Bus connection.